# Ubuntu 15.04 KVM VM Windows 7 Update

Tags: windows-7, linux-kvm

I am beginning my journey with Linux and Ubuntu. I've created a Windows 7 VM including the latest virtio-win driver installed for NIC (configured NAT), storage, and balloon.

My Windows 7 VM can get on the internet no problem, but Windows update will not run for some reason. It just sits there checking for updates indefinitely. Sits there spinning all night.

The host laptop is sitting behind a NAT router to the internet as well, but thought that would not matter.

Wondering anyone would have a comment?

Thanks!

Comment: Does Windows check if it's in a VM, and do things differently if it is? Like not update?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update does check the system to get driver updates and may in process know that if you are running on a VM. Although, this does not modify the behavior of the updater. Are you sure your network is configured correctly and all microsoft applications are able to connect to internet  By default, a WSUS server that is configured for the microsoft servers use port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. By default, the WSUS server uses port 8530 for HTTP and port 8531 for HTTPS if it is using the WSUS custom server (typically used by corporate). Make sure you can connect to https://windowsupdate.com.

Alternately, you can try restarting the wsus service `wuauserv` from services.msc.

Try rebooting into safe mode with networking and try running windows update here.

You can try this tutorial to reset the windows update :http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91738-windows-update-reset.html

Comment: Thank you for comments!  I still can't get Windows Update to kick off for some reason.  You did remind me of WSUS, for which I will try setting up internally...maybe will work that way.  I've run out of time.  Thanks again!